# Can doc2vec work on an artificial "text"?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I've created an artificial corpus (with 52624 documents). Each document is a list of objects (there are 461 of them).

So one possibility could be: `['chair', 'chair', 'chair', 'chair', 'chair', 'table', 'table']`

Here's a bar plot (log-scale) of the vocabulary.

[image]

And this is how I defined the model:

```
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=8, workers=4, min_count=1,epochs=40, dm=0)
```

Observing at:
`model.wv.most_similar_cosmul(positive = ["chair"])`

I see non related words

And it seems to me that the following works poorly as well:

```
inferred_vector = model.infer_vector(["chair"])
model.docvecs.most_similar([inferred_vector])
```

Where has my model failed?

**UPDATE**

There is the data (JSON file):

https://gofile.io/d/bZDcPX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Doc2Vec` & `Word2Vec` are often tried, and useful, on synthetic data. But whether they work may require a lot more tinkering, and atypical parameters, when the data doesn't reflect the same sort of correlations/distributions as the natural-language on which these algorithms were 1st developed.

First and foremost with your setup, you're using the `dm=0` mode. That's the `PV-DBOW` mode of the original "Paragraph Vector" paper, which specifically **does not** train word-vectors **at all**, only the doc-vectors. So if you're testing such a model by looking at word-vectors, your results will only reflect the random, untrained initialization values of any word-vectors.

Check the `model.docvecs` instead, for similarities between any doc-tags you specified in your data, and their may be more useful relationships.

(If you want your `Doc2Vec` model to learn words too – which isn't necessarily important, especially with a small dataset or where the doc-vectors are your main interest – you'd have to use either `dm=1` mode, or add `dbow_words=1` to `dm=0` so that the model adds interleaved skip-gram training. But note word-vector training may be weak/meaningless/harmful with data that's looks like it's just sorted runs of repeating tokens, as with your `['chair', 'chair', 'chair', 'chair', 'chair', 'table', 'table']` example item.)

Separately, using a very-low `min_count=1` is often a bad idea in such models - as such tokens with arbitrary idiosyncractic non-representative appearances do more damage to the coherence of surrounding more-common tokens than they help.

Comment: Many thanks! The idea of `min_conut=1` is that I don't want to lose any kind of object (it's not like a real language where you'd like to ignore esoteric words.  I thought that `dm=0` is more appropriate as the order of the words is irrelevant here. words-vector aren't important to me actually

Comment: Yes, if order isn't appropriate, `dm=0` makes a lot of sense – but then you should only be comparing the trained `tags`, not the words. (Or, if there were other reasons to try `dm=1`, shuffling each text so that any artificial relationships created by the insignificant-but-maybe-format-influenced ordering are thwarted, or using a massive `window` so that in essence, every word is in every other word's context.)

Comment: Even if the data isn't true natural-language, the insight that very-rare tokens are more trouble than they're worth may still apply. In many domains, overgeneralizing from a single first/idiosyncratic example is often worse than considering it neutral. Also with respect to doc-vectors in the classic setup, where each doc has its own unique ID: when a text includes a unique word in no other examples, DBOW training may over-emphasize that word (with no offsetting examples), or DM training may infuse that word's vector with some of the 'predictive power' you'd prefer to have in the doc-vector.